# Replacing variables in string with the values

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like:

```
const message = "Are you sure you want to delete the user {username} ?";
```

And I have an object with user properties like:-

```
const user = {
  id: 1,
  username: 'ABC',
  age: 34
};
```

So how can I replace the username in string with the actual value?

Comment: Is there any reason to not do it like
```const message = "Are you sure you want to delete the user " + user.username + " ?";
//or
const message = `Are you sure you want to delete the user ${user.username} ?`;```

Comment: I would look up template engines. There are many different template engines out there. Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach from what's out there so far:

```
const placeholderRegex = /\{(\w+?)}/g;

function populateTemplate(string, placeholders) {
  return string.replace(placeholderRegex, (_, name) => placeholders[name]);
}

const message = populateTemplate(
  "Are you sure you want to delete the user {username} ?", 
  user);
```

Answer (score 1):

`applyTemplate` function will loop through the provided object's keys.

If the {key} is present in your message, then it will be replaced globally.

```
function applyTemplate ( message, obj ) {
    for ( const key in obj ) {
      const lookup = new RegExp (`{${key}}`, 'g' );
      const value = obj[key];
      if ( lookup.test ( message ) ) {
          message = message.replace ( lookup, value)
      }
    }
    return message;
}

let mes = applyTemplate ( message, user );
console.log ( mes );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I saw the regex as a tag, I assume you want to solve this with regex and that the string is dynamic. You can do it like this:

```
const regex = /\{username\}/
const msg = "Are you sure you want to delete the user {username} ?"

replacedContent = msg.replace(regex, user.username)
```

First I define a regex that matches the existent username, after that, I replace the occurrence of that match with the new user.username. Regex does all the magic :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help :)... but I needed a function to pass the complete user object... that replaces each property name in the string.

Answer (score -1):

1) 
You can change the qoutes from '' to ``. 
and then use your obj.field, like this user.username
Inside the qoutes use such construction and put obj.field inside ${}. ${user.username}
So the whole construction will look like this:
const message = `Are you sure you want to delete the user ${user.username} ?`;

2) 
or the other way is to use this type ''(or "") of qoutes and use + symbol. 
const message = 'Are you sure you want to delete the ' + user.username + '?';